# How to use a Label as a parameter in custom SwiftUI View?

Tags: swiftui

I want to pass a `Label` to a custom UI component, but I can't figure out the syntax. Here's what I've got:

```
struct ProOnlyToggle: View {
    
    var label: Label // ERROR: Reference to generic type 'Label' requires arguments in <...>
    @Binding var isOn: Bool
    var tappedCallback: (() -> (Void))?
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appSettings: AppSettingsModel
    
    var body: some View {
        if !appSettings.canUseProFeatures {
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: label)
                .disabled(true)
                .onTapGesture {
                    tappedCallback?()
                }
        } else {
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: label)
        }
    }
}
```

How does one pass a Label into a custom control?

More background:

I'm building a toggle for a feature which is only available to customers who pay. If the user hasn't paid the toggle should be disabled and tapping it should take some action. Here's the kind of thing in vanilla SwiftUI

```
Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
    Text("Some pro feature")
    Text("more info")
       .font(.footnote)
}
.disabled(!isPro ? true : false)
.onTapGesture {
    if !isPro {
       tappedCallback?()
    }
}
```

Because I have quite a few of these switches, I'd like to make a reusable component that could be used like so:

```
// Note that is pro is passed into the @Environment
ProOnlyToggle(isOn: $settings.someToggle) {
    Text("Turn a thing on")
    Text("But be aware")
        .font(.footnote)
} tappedCallback: {
    // Do something in the UI
}
```

This feels quite simple, but I can't find any examples. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with 3 solutions.

**1. Use the generic View type instead of Label**

```
struct ProOnlyToggle<T: View>: View {
    
    init(@ViewBuilder label: @escaping ()->T, isOn: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.label = label
        self._isOn = isOn
    }

    let label: ()->T
    @Binding var isOn: Bool
    var tappedCallback: (() -> (Void))?
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: label)
            .disabled(true)
            .onTapGesture {
                tappedCallback?()
            }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use the component like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var isON: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ProOnlyToggle(label: { Label(title: { Text("Title Text") },
                                     icon: { Image(systemName: "heart") })},
                      isOn: $isON)
    }
}
```

**2. Use seperate Views for label's title and image**

```
struct ProOnlyToggle<L: View, I: View>: View {
    
    init(@ViewBuilder labelTitle: @escaping ()->L,
         @ViewBuilder labelIcon: @escaping ()->I,
         isOn: Binding<Bool>) {
        
        self.labelTitle = labelTitle
        self.labelIcon = labelIcon
        self._isOn = isOn
    }

    let labelTitle: ()->L
    let labelIcon: ()->I
    @Binding var isOn: Bool
    var tappedCallback: (() -> (Void))?
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: {
            Label(title: labelTitle, icon: labelIcon)
        })
            .disabled(true)
            .onTapGesture {
                tappedCallback?()
            }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the component like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var isON: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {      
        ProOnlyToggle(labelTitle: {Text("LabelTitle")},
                       labelIcon: {Image(systemName: "heart")},
                       isOn: $isON)
    }
}
```

**3. Implement and use a custom Label view**

```
struct CustomLabel: View {
    
    let title: String
    let systemImageName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Label(title: { Text(title)}, icon: { Image(systemName: systemImageName) } )
    }
}
```

Then, use the CustomLabel as a parameter in the "ProOnlyToggle" view.

```
struct ProOnlyToggle: View {
    
    let label: CustomLabel
    @Binding var isOn: Bool
    var tappedCallback: (() -> (Void))?
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: {
            label
        })
            .disabled(true)
            .onTapGesture {
                tappedCallback?()
            }
    }
}
```

And call the ProOnlyToggle anywhere in your app like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var isON: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ProOnlyToggle(label: CustomLabel(title: "Title Text",
                                         systemImageName: "heart"),
                      isOn: $isON)
    }
}
```

At this time, I have not found any better solutions. I hope it may help you.

Comment: As I was not using Text + Image but Text+Text only solution 1 was viable in my particular case. That said, it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: You need to call the label() closure in init and store the result in a let or you'll have problems

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer, added the init methods and changed variable properties of type () -> View to constants. Can you explain why you suggest using constants for view closures instead of variables?